# creating jquery mobile app with responsive image option in phonegap

Tags: html, image, jquery-mobile, responsive-design, phonegap-build

I am new to html, css and jquery. however i managed to create an app in phonegap. I am using jquery mobile. How to create a page with images that is responsive when the app is changed from portrait to landscape.

http://wordresearchcenter.org/stack.png

Answer (score 0):

Using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) CSS framework will make your page responsive by default.
A good simple and tutorial can be found at [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp)

Comment: @john, you can do what you want with a library, like bootstrap, but you can also do without it. The issues is *sometimes* the devices do not respond well to re-orientation. You may end up using [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) as your webview of choice. The downside is that crosswalk add more than 20Megs to the Application. I have added 50Megs in some trials. Lastly, you can do without the library and the crosswalk, but you'll have to paste together various assorted libraries. If you are interested, I have a list of leading blogs that can help.